# Python Pygame 当たり判定について

Tags: python, pygame

PythonのライブラリPygameの当たり判定についての質問です。
クラスBlockで画面上に壁を出現させて、矢印キーで自由に動かせるplayerの障害物にするという目的で書いたコードなのですが、なぜかL字型の壁の、
■ ↓
■ ■
矢印の壁に接触すると
■
■ ■ □←
矢印の位置にワープしてしまいます。
これが壁一つでは問題なく動作します。つまりはL字型の壁に配置した時だけ、特定の壁が予期しない挙動を見せます。原因解明をお願いします。

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 320))
pygame.display.set_caption('World_Collision')


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(160, 160))
        self.speed = 5

    def move(self):
        dx = dy = 0
        if move_left:
            dx -= self.speed
        if move_right:
            dx += self.speed
        if move_up:
            dy -= self.speed
        if move_down:
            dy += self.speed
        self.rect.x += dx
        for block in block_group.sprites():
            block.collide_x()
        self.rect.y += dy
        for block in block_group.sprites():
            block.collide_y()

    def update(self):
        self.move()


player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
player_group.add(player)

move_left = False
move_right = False
move_up = False
move_down = False


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    @staticmethod
    def create_block():
        for row_index, row in enumerate(Level):
            for column_index, column in enumerate(row):
                if column == 1:
                    block_group.add(Block(column_index * 32, row_index * 32))

    def collide_x(self):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, block_group):
            if self.rect.left < player.rect.left < self.rect.right:
                player.rect.left = self.rect.right
            if self.rect.left < player.rect.right < self.rect.right:
                player.rect.right = self.rect.left

    def collide_y(self):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, block_group):
            if self.rect.top < player.rect.top < self.rect.bottom:
                player.rect.top = self.rect.bottom
            if self.rect.top < player.rect.bottom < self.rect.bottom:
                player.rect.bottom = self.rect.top


block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
Level = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
Block.create_block()

while True:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move_up = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move_down = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move_up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                move_down = False

    player_group.draw(screen)
    player_group.update()

    block_group.draw(screen)
    block_group.update()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collide_x` と `collide_y` の定義に問題があります。

`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` はどれかのブロックと衝突している場合に真になりますが、Y 方向に衝突している場合でも `collide_x` 中で真になるので、そのまま `collide_x` の中の、どのブロックにめりこもうとしているのかという部分に進み、L 字型に右に飛び出した部分に X 方向的に左側からめり込んでいるものと判断され、右に飛び出したブロックの右端まで押し戻されます。

その後、Y 方向の移動処理が引き続き行われ、下に進んでいくわけです。

今回の質問に即した応急処置的には、`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` で真になった場合、さらに、**どのブロックと衝突しているのか？**　を `pygame` の命令を利用して行います。[`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) がそれですので、例えば次のようになります：

```
def collide_x(self):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, block_group):
        colliders = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_group, False)
        if colliders[0].rect.left < player.rect.left < colliders[0].rect.right:
            player.rect.left = colliders[0].rect.right
        elif colliders[0].rect.left < player.rect.right < colliders[0].rect.right:
            player.rect.right = colliders[0].rect.left

def collide_y(self):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, block_group):
        colliders = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_group, False)
        if colliders[0].rect.top < player.rect.top < colliders[0].rect.bottom:
            player.rect.top = colliders[0].rect.bottom
        elif colliders[0].rect.top < player.rect.bottom < colliders[0].rect.bottom:
            player.rect.bottom = colliders[0].rect.top
```

このコードはあくまでも今回の問題に即した解決策ですので、これが最良ではありません。`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` と `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` を使えば、そもそも下のように全ブロックを for ループでチェックすること自体が冗長になります。が、今回の問題の主旨からは外れますので、詳しい説明は割愛しますが、

```
self.rect.x += dx
for block in block_group.sprites():
    block.collide_x()
self.rect.y += dy
for block in block_group.sprites():
    block.collide_y()
```

この部分を次のようにしてブロックグループ全体で 1 回ずつ実行します：

```
self.rect.x += dx
Block.collide_x()
self.rect.y += dy
Block.collide_y()
```

`Block#collide_x` と `Block#collide_y` は、スタティックメソッドに書き換えます。

```
@staticmethod
def collide_x():
    # 略

@staticmethod
def collide_y():
    # 略
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。具体的にわからない箇所をまとめた後に、もう一つ質問させていただきます。

Comment: @Sean421 それもやはり `collide_x` と `collide_y` が `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` のみに依存しているからです。メインの次のループに入って新しくイベントを取得するまで `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` の状態は更新されないので、`collide_x` で位置が修正されようが関係なく、元の状態に基いて `collide_y` が続けて実行されるコードになってます。それで L 字の上に出張った部分のブロックに下からめり込もうとしていると判断されて、（L 字の上に出張った部分のブロックの下端の）下に弾かれる形になっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解いたしました。

Comment: 例えば、上方向から下に向かって、プレイヤーが壁.rect.left < player.rect.left < 壁.rect.rightで侵入した場合、collide_x()、collide_y()が実行された結果、上のロジックで行くとプレイヤーは壁の右上に配置されませんか…？すみません、どこか僕の認識に齟齬がありそうです汗